# Save a dictionary value in python functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am learning python and have one question about how to save a dictionary value via a python function.

```
import copy
def func():
    b = {'1':'d'}
    a = copy.deepcopy(b)
global a
a = {}
func()
print a
```

The printout is still `{}`, how to make it be `{'1':'d'}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say that you are accessing the `global` variable `a`, inside the function, like this

```
def func():
    global a
    b = {'1': 'd'}
    a = copy.deepcopy(b)
```

But, prefer not doing something like that. Instead, return the copy and then store it in the calling place, like this

```
import copy
a = {}


def func():
    b = {'1': 'd'}
    return copy.deepcopy(b)

a = func()
print a
```

Answer (score 1):

i moved the `global a` into the function definition.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import copy
def func():
    global a
    b = {'1':'d'}
    a = copy.deepcopy(b)
a = {}
func()
print a
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining 'a' in two different scopes, one in the "global" scope, one in the function scope.  You will need to return copy.deepcopy(b) and set that to the value of the outer defined 'a'.

```
import copy

def func():
    b = {'1':'d'}
    return copy.deepcopy(b)
global a

a = func()
print a
```